# Drawing directed graphs on Linux

Tags: graphics, graph

I need to draw (in a PDF or in a raster format) a directed acyclic graph.
The number of vertexes is low (in the order of tens) and I need to customize a bit how edges looks like. For example I'd like to have "wavy" edges, coloured edges and labels overs edges.

I heard of the dot language and Graphviz, which should do the job, but I wonder if it supports the kind of edge customizability I'm looking for.
So, the question: do you know any LaTeX package / application / library for Linux which does the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TiKZ was the package I was looking for. Easy to use, plenty of customization and tons of extensions make it nearly perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [yEd](http://www.yworks.com) for a decent application to do it (manually, it's a graph editor). There are various libraries and things to write code to do it as well, but whether you want an app or the ability to code your own depends on how often you need to do it, I guess...